# select default value is not working reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im triying to select by default a value into a select input but the input is not recognizing that value until i change it manually. By the default i set "All" as my default value. here is my code and the codesandbox link:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { FormField } from "react-form-input-fields";
import "react-form-input-fields/dist/index.css";

export default function App() {
  let [type, setType] = useState("All");
  const types = [
    { label: "All", value: "All" },
    { label: "Afganistan", value: "Afganistan" },
    { label: "Albania", value: "Albania" },
    { label: "Algeria", value: "Algeria" },
    { label: "American Samoa", value: "American Samoa" },
    { label: "Andorra", value: "Andorra" },
    { label: "Angola", value: "Angola" }
  ];

  function handletype(e) {
    setType(e);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2> */}
      <FormField
        type="select"
        value={type}
        option={types}
        label={"Select your type"}
        keys={"label"}
        handleOnChange={(value) => handletype(value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/select-problem-ykplcm

Comment: I guess that the problem is that the package you are using have 30 downloads and it's probably not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you use has a bug

The [source code](https://github.com/sivaprakashDesingu/react-form-input-fields/blob/dd7495a7f0e707b783cde8946d608d56ff0a7600/src/selectboxes/SingleSelect.js#L35) reveals that the `value` prop is only checked in `componendDidUpdate`, but this hooks is not called for the initial render

I would rather use a different library